# Intel Core i3-4* Graphics don't work on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xorg, intel-graphics

I'm trying to get Ubuntu 12.04 work with a Lenovo ThinkCentre M73 with an Intel Core i3-4130T. Ubuntu boots but when I login everything is flickering. Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't even detect the monitor. It only shows "Laptop". I upgraded the kernel from 3.2 to 3.13, which made the NIC work but graphics still don't work.

On an older Lenovo M72 with Intel Core i3-3* it worked.

lspci says:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 041e (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C220 Series Chipset Family H81 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
```

Upgrading to 14.04 is not an option at the moment.

How to get this graphics work on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it!

Ubuntu brings the xserver in many different versions. I installed the one from 14.04:

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty
```

This replaces the xserver and all of its drivers (and the kernel if not happened yet). Now Intel's Haswell graphics works.